# Alternating subgroup of symmetric group--is it considered a generalization of verbal?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, verbal-subgroups

The alternating subgroup ($A_n$) of the symmetric group($S_n$), is, I believe, not a verbal subgroup. But it is generated by elements of the form $xy$, where $x$ and $y$ have the same cycle structure. (Of course, that's equivalent to being generated by the $xy$, where $x$ and $y$ are transpositions.) That's a restriction on the elements $x$, $y$ "allowed" of taking the subgroup generated by all $xy$, a verbal subgroup, namely, the whole group $S_n$. So, is there a generalization of verbal subgroup already defined and studied, which $A_n$ would be an example of, where there you don't quantify over the whole group when defining your words? Does that generalization lead to more general theorems, perhaps slightly weaker than those for verbal subgroups?

Comment: The alternating group is the derived subgroup of the symmetric group, i.e. it is the verbal subgroup corresponding to the commutator word $[x,y] = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$.

Comment: Of course you're right, thanks. But I can well believe I said that it wasn't, knowing myself. However, perhaps the more general question still holds?